# Analyzing the relationship between the normal subgroups $N_1$ and $\langle N_2\cup N_3\rangle$ by way of an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let us be given the three normal subgroups $N_1,N_2,N_3$ of a group $G$ together with an isomorphism of $G$ onto $G/K_1\times G/K_2\times G/K_3$ defined by 
$$\pi(g)=(gK_1,gK_2,gK_3),$$
where $K_1=\langle N_2\cup N_3\rangle$, $K_2=\langle N_1\cup N_3\rangle$ and $K_3=\langle N_1\cup N_2\rangle$.

What is the relationship between each pair of subgroups $N_i$ and $K_i$? e.g. how do they interact with each other in this example (as quotient groups or otherwise)? Is the $K_i$ some sort of "complement" of the $N_i$?

(Is this a useless isomorphism?)

edit:

well, I can use this isomorphism to construct another isomorphism: $$N_1\times N_2\times N_3\rightarrow\pi^{-1}(\pi_1(N_1)\times\pi_2(N_2)\times\pi_3(N_3))$$ which sends $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to $x_1x_2x_3$. But I would like for the codomain to be G. Is that possible? Note that $\pi_i:G\rightarrow G/K_i$ is the canonical homomorphism.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @brian: well, I can use this isomorphism to construct another isomorphism: $N_1\times N_2\times N_3\rightarrow\pi^{-1}(\pi_1(N_1)\times\pi_2(N_2)\times\pi_3(N_3))$ which sends $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to $x_1x_2x_3$. But I would like for the codomain to be G. Is that possible? Note that $\pi_i:G\rightarrow G/K_i$ is the canonical homomorphism.

Comment: @user747209 Consider adding that to your question with an [edit].

Comment: If $N$ is normal, and $A$ is a subgroup, then $\langle N\cup A\rangle = NA = AN$. So your $K_1$ is equal to $N_2N_3$.